# How to add a recipe on a webpage to Google Assistant?

Tags: voice, google-home, structured-data, google-assistant, google-voice

[Google's structured data documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/recipe) states that you can enable the Google Assistant to guide users through your recipes on Google Home and smart displays by adding Recipe structured data to your webpage. We are planning on making a voice recipe book for visually impaired people and this option seemed better than making our own voice action.

However, I can't get it to work. I made [a test page with a dummy recipe (in Dutch)](https://receptentester-8979e.web.app/) and in the Google Search Console (GSC) I can see that it is indexed properly. The GSC says it recognises the Recipe. But when I google "smerige appeltaart van Chris Waalberg" I do see the search result, but it's not displayed as a rich recipe. Nor does my Google Home find it when I ask for it.

Is there a way to make sure Google Assistant includes my recipe as an option for its built in recipe guide?

Comment: Have you tested your webpage using the [Rich Results Test tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7445569)? You may also just need to ask Google to [recrawl the URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/recipe#add-structured-data).